# How to define an interface using another interface

Tags: go

In Go, how to define an interface using another interface?

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Interfaces
type Message interface {
    Read() string
}

type MessageReader interface {
    ReceiveMessages([]Message)
}

// Structs
type SQSMessage struct {
    Content string
}

type SQSMessageReader struct {
    Name string
}

// Implements
func (reader *SQSMessageReader) ReceiveMessages([]SQSMessage) {
}

func (msg *SQSMessage) Read() string {
    return msg.Content
}

// A function needs a reader interface
func FuncNeedsReader(MessageReader) {
    fmt.Println("get reader")
}

func main() {
    var reader SQSMessageReader
    FuncNeedsReader(reader)
}
```

I got error:

```
./prog.go:40:17: cannot use reader (type SQSMessageReader) as type MessageReader in argument to FuncNeedsReader:
    SQSMessageReader does not implement MessageReader (wrong type for ReceiveMessages method)
        have ReceiveMessages([]SQSMessage)
        want ReceiveMessages([]Message)
```

Do anyone know if this design is conflicting with Go's design?

I know we have "accept interfaces, return structs"
So I also tried https://play.golang.org/p/qdGaKRYAqw7, but still fail with similar error.

Comment: Notice the error message. Interface types are still distinct types, and the use of them does not have any impact on type equivalence (hence the "have" and "want" in the error is not satisfied). Essentially the only impact of interfaces on the type system is that it creates a new [assignability rule](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability). There is no further magic to do with type equivalence or deep conversions.

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems here.

First:

You have defined your `MessageReader` interface as:

```
type MessageReader interface {
    ReceiveMessages([]Message)
}
```

But you have defined your `ReceiveMessages` method on `SQSMessageReader` like this:

```
func (reader *SQSMessageReader) ReceiveMessages([]SQSMessage) {
}
```

Because it takes an `[]SQSMessage` parameter rather than `[]Message`, it *does not* implement the `MessageReader` interface. You would need to write:

```
func (reader *SQSMessageReader) ReceiveMessages([]Message) {
}
```

Second:

You have written:

```
func main() {
    var reader SQSMessageReader
    FuncNeedsReader(reader)
}
```

But `ReceiveMessages` has a *pointer* receiver (`func (reader *SQSMessageReader) ReceiveMessages...`), so you would need:

```
func main() {
    var reader SQSMessageReader
    FuncNeedsReader(&reader)
}
```

With these two changes, your code builds without errors.

Comment: Thank you! My understanding is golang do interface check statically and don't recursively check if a function's parameter is another interface. That's why in the 1st case, the function can only take the exact type.